# Graceful way to exit a dm_job ? System.exit()?

Tags: java, documentum, dfc

If I want to properly exit a documentum java job (if params are invalid for example), should I use a system.exit() or is there another way to do it.

As far as I know system.exit closes the virtual machine, does it have an effect on other jobs running?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Definitely don't use System.exit(). If you're on  a method server this may try to shutdown the server. In most cases this will raise a SecurityException (depending on the security policy defined for the server).

Like Michael said your job is running in the **execute** method so any return statement from that method should end the job.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are referring to a subclass of the **com.documentum.job.Job** abstract class you should be able to exit the **execute()** method by **return false;**. If you wish to abort instead you could call the **abort()** method (you may need to have the **canAbort()** method return true as well). You could also

Either way, I wouldn't recommend calling **System.exit()** except in very unusual circumstances.